# A suitable native Windows development platform for a .NET developer

Tags: .net, windows, native

Greetings to this great community. Here is my question.

During development of .NET Windows applications I keep running into the same problem over and over:

I am eager to use the latest and greatest .NET framework with all the shiny new features, but that requires the user to have that version of .NET installed, which in turn requires an at least moderately up to date version of Windows.

This turns out to be OK in a corporation/private setting, where you can request the client to conform to the requirements.

But when developing applications for clients who want to give the application to outside users of any kind, this quickly grows into a huge problem. 250 MB .NET downloads and limited Windows version compatibility are a big no-no.

I have tried several products that claim to enable the .NET application to work without the .NET framework, but the only ones that work do their job by some form of virtualization, which ends up with huge executables (upward of 100 MB). This is just not the natural way of doing things.

As much as I understand it, my only way of going around this problem is turning to native application development. This rules out all the "cool" kinds of development, such as .NET and Java right away.

.NET seems to be for development under "controlled conditions", while native applications are "for the wild".

I need an up to date development platform, with a good IDE, capable of creating applications for all currently used Windows versions (XP SP1 and upwards would be OK). Also, a language close to C# and libraries close to .NET are preferred, but not a must.

To my knowledge, Visual C++ can create native applications in Visual Studio, but I am worried this is more of an afterthought for MS.

There is also Delphi, which seems to be centered around doing just what I need done.

What development platform would you recommend? (others are also an option) Am I wrong entirely and .NET development is actually suitable for a broad clientbase of non-technical users?

long-winded, I know :)

Comment: What are you developing? What are it's requirements for the client side? What kind of client profiles are there? How are you likely to deploy? I think you need to do more homework before picking platform.

Comment: Moderately up-to-date version of Windows? .NET 4.0 runs on Windows XP; you need to write apps for Windows 2000?  .NET 2.0, a fine framework, runs on Windows 98. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z6watww.aspx

Comment: Nobody ever complains about the ~3 gigabyte Windows install that's required.  Yet the 50 MB for .NET 2 is a problem.  Makes no sense of course.  Simply make a .NET install a prerequisite, just like the Windows install.  So somebody else takes care of it.

Comment: Unfortunately, supporting XP SP1 and up is a requirement. That rules out .NET 4.0, and .NET 3.5 as well... Leaving me without WPF support altogether (my weapon of choice). The application will go to about 100 end-users in different organizations, frequently without dedicated IT support. The application needs to be e-mailable and able to survive a copy/paste to another computer. Also needs to have its local database. I had to jump through so many hoops just to have the DB work without installing the SQL Server CE. And I have to notice - that DB engine is so slow...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embarcadero Delphi is for your case. By the way, Delphi and C# have the same creator - [Anders Hejlsberg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anders_Hejlsberg).

When I faced the same question you are facing right now I decided the following:

People who pay for software are in the developed countries, such as US and EU.
In these countries, people are more swift to upgrade the OS.
So the person who is more likely to buy my software has Vista at least, therefore has .Net 3.

But surely it's up to you to harness the power of native development, or to stick with simpler and cleaner, but more limitly applicable solutions.

Also, I personally would not recommend using Visual Studio as a development environment for C++ Native projects, since, after .Net, developing in C++ seems to much of a headache.

Comment: I would like to be able to limit the OS version like that, and might do that if I was selling the the application outright, or making something for other developers. But the tool I am making for the current customer goes to government and science institute users, many of whom have older Windows versions, and don't even admin privileges... I have spent way too much time making everything work just on the few clients test machines, and had to downgrade from .NET 4 to .NET 3.5 to do it. It seems I'll have to go native, while the project is still young :)

Comment: I currently live and work in Ukraine. Here, most governmental institutions are equipped with Windows 2000 workstations. We are successfully able to deploy software to a large number (30.000+) Win2K machines via AD group policy, still having these machines install .Net 2 before installing our package. Going Native is resonalble if: you are writing a driver-related software. You are targeting the end user market. From my point of view, of cause.